# Beamer : \item<only@+>. Same height for each \item?

Tags: beamer, enumerate, overlays

I would like the height to be constant for each item (automatically sized to the highest one). Like "overprint" would do without enumerate.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{example}
        Have a look to :
            \begin{enumerate}[<only@+>]
                \item One line
                \item Two\\ lines
                \item And now\\three\\lines
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{example}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you complete this to a minimal compilable document including which beamer theme you are using.

Comment: Have a look at my second edited answer, I would highly recommend this one over the other!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `only` will not allocate space for the other items. You need to use another method in your case (see [beameruseguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) chapter 9: Creating Overlays). You need to do this manually (as far as I know, but surely you can automate it, wait for the latex pros), selecting the largest item and use `\onslide+` there. The rest will be fine with `\onslide*`. I created the following solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newcommand{\tlap}[1]{\raisebox{0pt}{#1}}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\tlap{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\item {\vspace{-2.2ex} \strut#1\strut}}}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{example}
    Have a look to :
    \begin{enumerate}
        \onslide*<1>{\myitem{One line}}%
        \onslide*<2>{\myitem{Two\\lines}}%
        \onslide+<3>{\myitem{And now\\three\\lines}}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The trick here is to use `only` or `\onslide*` (doesn't allocate space) for the shorter items and `visible` or `\onslide+` (allocates the space) for the longest item.

I don't know why, but using `\item` in a parbox leads to a space at the top part of enumeration. That's why I added the `\vspace`, looks fine to the eye, but hopefully there is a better approach. By the way I assume you want to use the `itemize` environment, instead of `enumeration`? Enumeration in this case doesn't make much sense to me...

I added the `\rlap` just for testing purposes, seeinig the items on one slide.

**edit:** This doesn't seem to work properly, if there is no text immediately above the `enumerate` environment. The first entry will always be too low then, the rest seems to be alright. Probably the `\vspace` adjustment is no more needed if this is fixed. Any ideas why?

**edit2:** To save you a lot of trouble and without the need for some fancy stuff, it might be easier to just allocate the space needed in this example environment, I would favor this approach a lot!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newenvironment{examplefix}[1]{\begin{example}\begin{minipage}[t][#1\baselineskip]{\linewidth}}{\end{minipage}\end{example}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{examplefix}{4}
        Have a look to :
        \begin{enumerate}[<only@+>]
            \item One line
            \item Two\\ lines
            \item And now\\three\\lines
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{examplefix}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```